# Multi update position based on ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

it might be a silly question but I am struggling with postgres update. I have following table:

```
id | tableX_id| position |
---+----------+---------+
 1 |    10    |         |    
 2 |    10    |         |    
 3 |    10    |         |    
 4 |    10    |         |    
 5 |    10    |         |    
 6 |    11    |         |    
 7 |    11    |         |    
 8 |    12    |         |
```

I need to update position like this:

```
    id | tableX_id| position |
    ---+----------+---------+
     1 |    10    |    1    |    
     2 |    10    |    2    |    
     3 |    10    |    3    |    
     4 |    10    |    4    |    
     5 |    10    |    5    |    
     6 |    11    |    1    |    
     7 |    11    |    2    |    
     8 |    12    |    1    |
```

I have following update that doesnt work(update all position to 1):

```
UPDATE tableY y 
SET position = subquery.pos 
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as pos 
  FROM tableY y2 
  JOIN tableX x on x.id = y2.tableX_id
) as subquery
```

Comment: `OVER (partition by tableX_id)`?.. also need to see tableX to tell

Comment: lets say its just id attribute in tableX and we have connection table - tableX_tableY with attributes: tableX_id,tableY_id

Comment: then my suggestion should work

Comment: UPDATE tableY y SET position = subquery.pos 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by tableX_id) as pos FROM tableY y2 
JOIN tableX x on x.id = y2.tableX_id) as subquery . Unfortunately it doesnt work :/

Comment: Why do you want to do this at all? You can always get the row number based on the data you already have, so why store it redundantly? You shouldn't.

Comment: And anyway: Did you expect the DBMS to guess by which criteria to number the rows? Isn't it obvious that you must give `ROW_NUMBER` some information on what to do?

Comment: Its just simplified case, i need to do that because som other functionality will rely on that position and in some cases hibernate return list of X object in incorrect position, so I want something to rely on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `where subquery.id = tableY.id`, as below:

```
t=# update x set position = pos
from (select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by x order by id) as pos FROM x) sub
where x.id = sub.id;
UPDATE 8
Time: 10.015 ms
t=# select * from x;
 id | x  | position
----+----+----------
  1 | 10 |        1
  2 | 10 |        2
  3 | 10 |        3
  4 | 10 |        4
  5 | 10 |        5
  6 | 11 |        1
  7 | 11 |        2
  8 | 12 |        1
(8 rows)
```

Comment: No, the `OVER` clause is still incomplete. You must specify an `ORDER BY` clause of course in order to get reliable results. Your query lacks an `ORDER BY` clause, too.

Comment: yes - to get reliable result I need to specify order - true.

Comment: UPDATE tableY y SET position = subquery.pos FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by y2.tableX_id order by y2.id) as pos FROM tableY y2) as subquery where y.id = subquery.id   THIS WORKS! Thank you :)